# Get Credentials from Amazon Cognito in pure Java

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-polly

how can I get credentials like `access key` `security key` and `session token` from Amazon Cognito Identity in pure java using only `IDENTITY_POOL_ID` and `Region`?

Like on Android but without application context

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
  getApplicationContext(), // Context
  "IDENTITY_POOL_ID", // Identity Pool ID
  Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
);
```

Is it possible with Amazon SDK for Java or pure Http request? If it is, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've  found a solution, `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` extends `CognitoCredentialsProvider` so just use base class

```
CognitoCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCredentialsProvider(
            COGNITO_POOL_ID,
            MY_REGION
    );
```